# Show that the vectors $(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1),$ and $(0, 1, 1)$ generate $F^3.$

Tags: solution-verification, vector-spaces

Show that the vectors $(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1),$ and $(0, 1, 1)$ generate $F^3.$

I tried solving the problem as follows:

Let $a,b,c\in F$ such that $a(1,1,0)+b(1,0,1)+c(0,1,1)=(x,y,z)$ for some $(x,y,z)\in F^3.$  This means, $(a,a,0)+(b,0,b)+(0,c,c)=(x,y,z).$  So, we obtain the following system of equations,

$a+b=x,b+c=y,$ and $c+a=z.$

This means $a+b-(b+c)=x-y\implies a-c=x-y.$ We have, $a+c=z$ and we can say, $2a=x-y+z\implies a=\frac{x-y+z}{2}$ and as, $a+c=z$ we have, $c=z-a=\frac{2z-x+y-z}{2}=\frac{-x+y+z}{2}$ and finally, $b=\frac{x+y-z}{2}.$

---

Surprisingly,  this answer i.e,  $a=\frac{x-y+z}{2},b=\frac{x+y-z}{2}$ and $c=\frac{-x+y+z}{2}$ matched with that of the book. But I did all the operations in this solution assuming $F=\Bbb R$ e.g. $2a=x-y+z\implies a=\frac{x-y+z}{2},$ or, $c=z-a=\frac{2z-x+y-z}{2}=\frac{-x+y+z}{2}$ and so on. Was I correct in assuming $F=\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: sadly not, because this is false in $F_2$

Comment: The book should say something about $F$. This works if and only if [$2\neq0$ in $F$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)).

Comment: @Exodd What is false in $F_2$ ?

Comment: It's false that those three vectors span ${\mathbb F_2}^3$. They're linearly dependent; their sum is $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Your system is wrong. It should be$$a+b=x,a+c=y,b+c=z.$$

Comment: @mr_e_man So, should I skip this question?

Comment: No, don't skip the question, just note in your answer that the result fails to hold for fields of characteristic $2$. (Or the equivalent if $F$ is not a field).

Comment: @PaulSinclair But can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: (Assuming $F$ is a field - you never said what it was, and it might be a division algebra, for example), what still needs solved? Your calculation is valid (with Anne Bauval's correction) in all fields whose characteristic is not $2$. It is not valid in fields of characteristic $2$ as there $2 = 0$ and is not invertible. And in that case, the three vectors sum to $0$ and are thus not linearly independent. so cannot span the 3D vector space $F^3$. What is left?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I posted the question in the exact same way, it was presented. But then can I take my assmption and my solution valid ?

Comment: There was no mention in your source of what $F$ is, at all. NONE??? Just "$F$" without any explanation whatsoever? I'm sorry, but unless your source was another internet post like this, I do not believe you. I find it far, far more likely that you just didn't bother to examine the context of the problem to find where this information was in fact spelled out. Possibly in some introduction to the problem set, possibly in the section of the text containing the problem set. Possibly even in the opening of the book as a general convention used throughout the book. But definitely *somewhere*.